# django-cms: Advance theme management

Tags: python, django, django-cms

For my django CMS site i need to manage the entire theme of the templates from admin panel. It includes link text colour, hover text background, button colour etc.

I found the app https://github.com/MegaMark16/django-cms-themes, but i can be used with predefined themes only.And i want the admin, who doesnt have any idea about CSS, will be able to manage the theme of the entire website using tools such as colour pallettes etc..

Is there any django app that can be used for this instead of django-cms-themes ?

Thanks in Advance....